# Proof of certainty equivalence

Tags: microeconomics, uncertainty

The questions say two lotteries are denoted L1 = (0.3,0.7,0.0) and L2= (0.9,0.0,0.1) and denote c(L1) and c(L2) the certainty equivalents of those two lotteries.

Then prove L1 ≻ L2 if and only if c(L1) > c(L2) and state any assumptions needed to arrive at the result.

Isn't this very straight forward because u(CE)=E(u(x))?!?

Comment: @1muflon1: I thought $u(CE)=E(u(x))$ is what defines $CE$, isn't it? I think you meant $u(CE)\ne u(E(x))$ or $CE\ne E(x)$ in general.

Comment: That is what I thought, too. Hence, u(L1)=u(CE1)>u(L2)=u(CE2) so that we have u(CE1)>u(CE2) and therefore CE1>CE2 for any standard (i.e., increasing) utility function. Maybe the question was simply after this monotonicity?

Comment: @HerrK. oh you are right my bad, I am retracting my comment